# Why am I getting a WaitingforActivation TaskStatus

Tags: c#

I am trying to use async and await commands on a form with VS2012 framework 4.5.
My async method SlowMethodAsync does not return anything. Note this code works fine in a Console application.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task =  SlowMethodAsync();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus status = task.Status;

     Console.WriteLine("Slow method result on Thread: {0}", task.Result);    //This line never executes
    Console.WriteLine("Main complete on {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

//Why is this method not returning anything?

static async Task<int> SlowMethodAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Slow method started on Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    Console.WriteLine("Slow method complete on Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    return 42;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've caused a deadlock.

Using `task.Result` blocks the UI thread - it can't complete until the task returned by `SlowMethodAsync` completes.

However, because `SlowMethodAsync` was originally launched with a synchronization context also on the UI thread, the continuation after `await` *also* wants to execute on the UI thread.

So `Result` can't complete until the async method completes... and the async method can't complete until `Result` has completed.

Instead, you should make your `button1_Click` method async too, and then use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Slow method result on Thread: {0}", await task);
```

The reason this would have worked in a console app was that the `SlowMethodAsync` method wouldn't have had any particular synchronization context to come back to, so the continuation could execute on any thread pool thread - which wouldn't be blocked by the "main" thread waiting on the task.

Comment: Solid answer, as usual. I have worked on multiple teams where a majority of the developers did not understand the context their threads were executing in (more commonly resulting in exceptions when they attempted to update UI items from a non-ui synchronization context). I think this represents a failing in the API's documentation to make some caveats clear to developers who are not knowledgeable in operating system/parallel programming concepts (one of the core groups that this nifty API is trying to service). Any idea how the community can remedy this?

Comment: @marr75: There's a *huge* amount of documentation around threading in WinForms UIs. Likewise there's a lot of information around about what async methods do, although that's definitely a more advanced topic. The problem isn't one of a lack of documentation, IMO - it's a lack of people *reading* documentation.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's probably a much more accurate assessment. Would you say this is a case where requiring the developer to provide the context explicitly would be useful?

Comment: @marr75: No, because once you *do* know what you're doing, it's really nice the way the context flows. But it does take a while to get used to.

Comment: @marr75: The context capture/resume is documented well on MSDN, blogs, the `async` FAQ, and `async` intro articles. The deadlock scenario in particular was first explicitly documented in January 2011 (on an MSDN blog), has been demo'd twice on Channel9, published in MSDN magazine, and is still repeatedly asked and answered on SO and MSDN forums. Not sure where or how else it *can* be documented...

Comment: Sadly, despite having seen it in those places personally, it never reaches 75% of the people I work with.

Comment: that works but now i just null back instead of a json of the item I want back.

Comment: @php-jquery-programmer: I suggest you ask a new question with more context - there's no way we can help you with only that information.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I actually figured it out, Though I have hit another with getting NULL back even though I clearly see data when I added a breakpoint and ran through the code.